# if elseif statement with three condition where second condition is between two number Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, if-statement

I want to filter results based on three conditions in Laravel view blade. I wrote this code but is not giving me the right results because I second condition has to be between two numbers. My code:

```
@foreach($post_array[$key] as $array)
    @if($array['diff'] <= 168)
        <td>{{ $count }}<td>
    @elseif($array['diff'] > (168) && (720))
        <td>{{ $count }}<td>
    @elseif($array['diff'] > 720)
        <td>{{ $count }}<td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($post_array[$key] as $array)
    @if($array['diff'] <= 168)
        <td>{{ $count }}<td>
    @elseif(($array['diff'] > 168) && ($array['diff'] < 720))
        <td>{{ $count }}<td>
    @elseif($array['diff'] > 720)
        <td>{{ $count }}<td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```